# css sprites or Image map?

Tags: css, html, imagemap, sprite

first and foremost the link to my site is

http://graph-art.matc.edu/harrisd5/vicom123/assign2/index.html

I"m a student new to web development...please for me???

The navigation below my images I wanted to change the color About/prices/locations
into the color of Services and gallery boxes when hover over it.....and vice versa About/prices/locations.

I also wanted wanted to change the color of all of them when click which I believe is active???

I wanted to know how can I accomplish this do I use css sprites or image map?????

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

Image Map, if you want a quick solution. But controls on each elements (and changing colors on 'hover') etc., are difficult to achieve.

CSS Sprites is a bit advanced CSS programming. Besides it only makes sense to use one if you have a very high traffic website (to save bandwidth, etc.), otherwise it is as good as not using one. Understanding co-ordinate geometry is an advantage here :)

Hope this helps.